How to get data from a file stored in android app, using kotlin jetpack compose
My problem is that I can't find out the file directory. The file directory inside my computer doesn't match the one inside my android app.
How can I get the path for the file without having to type it manually
I tried using the absolutePathString from Path, it doesn't seem to work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
